# Nextjs production build problem (Links do not work)

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js

I have built a website in next.js and expressjs and it works great in development. But when I run `next build` I get thing that does not occur in development.

I want to write few points that does happen in production only.

- Few links do not work

```
<li style={{marginLeft: '-50px'}}>
     <Link href={`/profile/?user_slug=${router.query.user_slug}`} as={`/profile/${router.query.user_slug}`}>
        <a className={`${classes.textSize} ${router.route === "/profile/user_slug" ? classes.active1 : ''}`}>User</a>
     </Link>
</li>
<li>
      <Link  href={`/profile/?user_slug=${router.query.user_slug}/questions`} as={`/profile/${router.query.user_slug}/questions`}>
        <a className={`${classes.textSize} ${router.route === "/profile/user_slug/questions" ? classes.active1 : ''}`}>Ques</a>
      </Link>
</li>
```

Few links in navigation bar do not work when I am on certain page. I have route https://example.com/profile/user_name. Here user_name is dynamic. I have noticed when I am on profile page and if I try to visit home or questions route this does not work.

In layout I have

```
{!mobile && <Button className={classes.button}><Link href='/'><a className={classes.link}>Home</a></Link></Button>}
{!mobile && <Button className={classes.button}><Link href='/questions'><a className={classes.link}>Questions</a></Link></Button>}
```

These two simple links do not work. I don't know why

- I get error in console saying 404 such as

  https://example.com/_next/static/u46GEnW5PnfCBXwLuWy-M/pages/category/%5Bcategory_name%5D.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

  https://example.com/_next/static/u46GEnW5PnfCBXwLuWy-M/pages/question.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

I have defined all the routes in express

```
  app.get('/profile/:user_slug', (req, res) => {
    return nextApp.render(req, res, '/profile/user_slug', { user_slug: req.params.user_slug })
  })

  app.get('/profile/:user_slug/questions', (req, res) => {
    return nextApp.render(req, res, '/profile/user_slug/questions', { user_slug: req.params.user_slug })
  })

  app.get('/profile/:user_slug/followers', (req, res) => {
    return nextApp.render(req, res, '/profile/user_slug/followers', { user_slug: req.params.user_slug })
  })

  app.get('/profile/:user_slug/followings', (req, res) => {
    return nextApp.render(req, res, '/profile/user_slug/followings', { user_slug: req.params.user_slug })
  })
```

How do I solve it for production. Everything works great in development.

Answer (score 0):

Let's check this article: [solving-next-static-pages-js-404-not-found](https://www.loudnoises.us/solving-next-static-pages-js-404-not-found/)

> ### next.config.js
>
> ```
> module.exports = {
>   ...
>   distDir: "_next",
>   generateBuildId: async () => {
>     if (process.env.BUILD_ID) {
>       return process.env.BUILD_ID;
>     } else {
>       return `${new Date().getTime()}`;
>     }
>   },
>   ...
> }
> ```

---

if the above doesn't help you. Please double-check that running instance on the production server. Maybe is run more than a single application instance with a different bundle and you have a race to sources.